# A question on electric current

Tags: electricity, electric-current, charge

In my physics book the definition of current is

> If a charge $∆Q$ crosses an **area** in time $∆t$, we define the average electric current through the area during this time as
> $I=\frac{∆Q}{∆t}$. The current at time $t$ is $I=\lim_{∆t\to0} \frac{∆Q}{∆t}=\frac{dQ}{dt}$

And the definition of current density is

> If $∆I$ is the current through the **area** $∆S$, the (same as the top) ...  $J=\frac{dI}{dS}$

My question is what is the difference between the 1st definition **area** and the 2nd one?

Comment: Use $\Delta$ instead of ∆

Comment: And in fact, both the areas being talked about are the same! It's just a matter of how you want to calculate it; whether you want the current through only half the wire's cross-section or 3 quarters of it.

Comment: It is the same area. Its symbol is only needed for the density equation, so doesn't appear in the one it is not needed for.

Comment: Still I am feeling somthing. The first area can be anything, right? In the first one the area doesn't matter. But if dI=J.dS then area does matter and it could not be anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total current $I$ through a surface is a global quantity (with respect to the surface). The current density $\bf J$ is a vector and it is a function of the point, in general. The integral over the surface of $\bf J \cdot n$ is the total current $I$, $\bf n$ being a unit vector orthogonal to each surface element. If the surface is so small that variations of $\bf J$ over the surface can be neglected, and if the surface is orthogonal to the direction of $\bf J$ there is a relation between the small surface area $\Delta S$, $|{\bf J}|$, and the total current through the same surface: $I=|{\bf J}| \Delta S.$ If the unit vector makes an angle $\theta$ with $\bf J$ the previous formula becomes:
$$
I=|{\bf J}| \Delta S\cos \theta.\tag{1}
$$
The right-hand side can be interpreted as the product of the modulus of the density current by the *cross-sectional area* of the surface element.

Summarizing: if $I$ is the total current through a small surface element $\Delta S$ and we want to connect it to an underlying current density ${\bf J}$ the surface element must be the same, in general. However, formula $(1)$ tells us that many surface areas, oriented to give the same cross-sectional area, will give the same total current.

Comment: Ya, now it is clear from your first line. Thank u